# List is still empty after function call

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python. I want to input an array of integer via the command line.

This works like a charm:

```
number = []
number = map(int,raw_input().split())
```

But if I put it into a function:

```
def data_entry(array_input):
    array_input = map(int,raw_input().split())
if __name__=='__main__':
    number = []
    data_entry(number)
```

then `print len(number)` will always return `0`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html), specifically the sections on assignment, variables, and functions.

Comment: One way is to `return` the result of `data_entry()` function ... read in the official manual about functions...

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use a `return` statement in your function:

```
def data_entry():
    return map(int,raw_input().split())

if __name__=='__main__':
    number = data_entry()
    print len(number)
```

Currently your function creates and modifies a local copy of number, the original stays unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the new list is an option but there is a possibility to code what you originally wanted.
But first an important lesson!

**The problem is the following:**

`array_input` is just a name bound to the list object in this case `number`.
When you now pass it to the function the list will be bound to the name `array_input` in the scope of the function.

When writing `array_input = map(int,raw_input().split())` you are **binding** the name `array_input` to a **new** list, because `map(...)` creates a new list.

If you want to modify your old list, you would have to copy the objects **in** the new list to the old one.

**old code with comments:**

```
def data_entry(array_input):
    # map() creates a new list and array_input is bound to it
    # the binding to your original list is lost!
    array_input = map(int,raw_input().split())
```

**New version with correct behaviour:**

```
#test-input: 1 2 3
def data_entry(array_input):
    #bind the list created by map to a new name
    new_arr = map(int, raw_input().split())
    #loop through the new list and append the objects to the original list
    for obj in new_arr:
        array_input.append(obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = []
    data_entry(number)
    print(number)

>>[1, 2, 3]
```